# Creating Local PDF Report using SSRS 2017 RDLC file

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc

I'm having an issue when attempting to create a PDF report from an RDLC template. I'm getting the following errors

```
1 - "DefinitionInvalidException: The definition of the report 'Reports\rptDeletedCorpCap.rdlc' is invalid"

2 - "ReportProcessingException: The report definition is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services. This could be the result of publishing a report definition of a later version of Reporting Services, or that the report definition contains XML that is not well-formed or the XML is not valid based on the Report Definition schema. Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded."
```

This seems easy enough to identify, the DLL I'm using is for an older version of Reports but I cannot seem to find an updated version of that DLL

I'm using version **11.0.2802.16** of **Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.DLL**

Is there an easy fix to get this RDLC working with that DLL or does anyone know of a newer report tool that will allow me to create a PDF output within a console application?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with this issue,
I was able to resolve it by downloading the package **Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms v15**. This was up to date and compatible with the 2016 schema and allowed me to generate my PDF :)